# ¿Como testear datos de un Entry mediante Unitest?

Tags: python, tkinter, pruebas-unitarias

**Buenas!**

Estoy tratando de testear el valor de un Entry en Python mediante Unittest.

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andres/PycharmProjects/Pruebas/test_aplicacion.py", line 14, in test_uno
    self.assertEqual(self.App.obtener_dia(letras), "abc")
TypeError: obtener_dia() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dia'
```

Si me pudiera ayudar con una solución para poder realizar el test 
le comparto mi Codigo

**Clase Aplicación**

```
import tkinter as tk


class AppGUI(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(root, args, **kwargs)
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Aplicaciones de Pruebas")

        self.dia = tk.StringVar()
        frame = tk.Frame(root)
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        label_titulo = tk.Label(frame, text="Inserte un Dia")
        label_titulo.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="n")

        insert_dia = tk.Entry(frame, width=30, textvariable=self.dia)
        insert_dia.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w", padx=5, pady=5)

        boton_dia = tk.Button(frame, text="Listo!", command=lambda: self.obtener_dia(self.dia))
        boton_dia.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="e", padx=5, pady=5)

    def obtener_dia(self, dia):
        print(dia.get())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    AppGUI(root).place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    root.mainloop()
```

**Clase Test**

```
import unittest
from aplicacion import AppGUI
from tkinter import *

class testApplication(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.master= Tk()
        self.valor= StringVar()
        self.App=AppGUI

    """Testear el Ingreso de Letras dentro del Entry"""
    def test_uno(self):
        letras=self.valor.set("abc")
        self.assertEqual(self.App.obtener_dia(letras), "abc")



if __name__=='__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Mi Pregunta es cómo se realiza un test a un valor dado por la misma interfaz gráfica. Y como controlar las excepciones en Python. No se si alguien tenga algún tutorial como poder realizar pruebas unitarias a las aplicaciones mediante Tkinter o en que parte del código me estoy equivocado.

Muchas Gracias por la Ayuda!